# how to fix the problem Razorpay iOS implementation

Tags: ios, swift, razorpay

in iOS implementation of Razorpay swift5.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Swift version 5.1+, ensure that you declare var razorpay: RazorpayCheckout!. For versions lower than 5.1, you may use var razorpay: Razorpay!.

Alternatively, you can use the following alias and retain the variable as Razorpay.

typealias Razorpay = RazorpayCheckout